# Legal issues when using a paper

Tags: algorithms, digital-communications

I'm just curious about the copyright issues when publishing a paper on the Internet. Can some simply take the idea I explained in a manuscript and implement it for his own work? (e.g. using some programming language)

Obviously I'm supposing that: I haven't made public my own implementation (personal or for a company), the person acquired a legal copy of the document from a magazine (Springer, IEEE, etc), he fully understood the idea, he wrote his own lines of code, and he is properly citing the original paper.

I understand this is an affair that students are continuously facing when working in their thesis.

Comment: It's a good question, but not one that we are equipped to answer.  Legal questions are off-topic here.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a legal question.

Comment: C'mon :) A lot of people in this forum must be interested in this, besides, I haven't heard about any Legal Stack Exchange site, and the papers are related to DSP stuff...

Comment: You could try your luck on the Academia site, as it has to do with published papers. As far as I know, as long as he/she is citing the paper correctly there are no problems with using the ideas from the paper. That's what you publish a paper for, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Academic publications are in the public knowledge domain. If it is not patented before publication, you could perfectly implement and use the idea. The non-patented academic works are a part of open science.